# Unable to range beacon with infinite time in Background mode, even after set "allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates" to TRUE

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager, clbeaconregion

I am using **CLLocationManager** object to start beacon ranging as per below code.
Also enable the Background mode from Target -> Capabilities.

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

Also add the AllowsBackgroundLocatoinUpdates to YES

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9) {
   locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
}
```

A Boolean value indicating whether the app wants to receive location updates when suspended.

Created on **CLBeaconRegion** object to range beacon like as

```
CLBeaconRegion *beacon_Region;
beacon_Region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:mjorVa minor:minorVa identifier:tmpStrIdentifier];
beacon_Region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
beacon_Region.notifyOnEntry=YES;
beacon_Region.notifyOnExit=YES;
[locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beacon_Region];
```

It's ranging in Background mode in some period of time like 10 minutes or some time 20 minutes but not in infinite.

Answer (score 0):

**How to maximize beacon responsiveness:**

**1**.For the fastest monitoring detection times in the foreground, do ranging whenever you are monitoring, even if you don’t care about ranging updates. Like this:

```
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"] major: 1 minor: 1 identifier: @"region1"];
region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
[_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
```

**2**.If you want to get a guaranteed extra monitoring update in the background whenever the users wakes up their phone, set the notifyEntryStateOnDisplay option on your region as so:

```
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"] major: 1 minor: 1 identifier: @"region1"];
region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

IF YOU WANT TO MORE THEN PLEASE FOLLOW THIS [ARTICLE](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want to range beacon in infinite time with background mode. Without breaking **didRangeBeacons:inRegion** method.